# jquery clone and after

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been having an issue resizing some images that are hidden by a closed bootstrap modal. The images are layered on top of each other, so they have to be absolute positioned. I want to correct the size of the image container, so that when the modal is opened they don't look strange.

I have a fast resize function, but it will only work once the images are visible. It is used when the user resizes the browser window. Using it for this means that the user sees the non-resized container for a small preiod of time.

The function below is supposed to be run only once when the pages loads and after all the images have finished loading (that is working). The issue is that for some reason the original modal is removed along with the cloned one. If I remove the `.remove()` from the jQuery chain then the clone remains, but the orginal still gets removed.

```
var cloneCounter = 0;

// Slow resize using jquery becuase
// the images are hidden.
function slowResize( parent, pId ) {
  // height of the largest image
  var largest = 0;

  var newId = "clone-" + cloneCounter + "-";

  // |find the modal that the parent is cloeset to
  // |-clone the modal
  // |--change the id of the clone
  // |--find all elements
  // |---change all the child ids
  // |--insert the clone into the dom
  // |--show the modal
  // |--hide it from view, make dimensions ( position: absolute, display: block, visibility: hidden )
  // |--find all the images related to the parent passed in
  // |---calculate which is the tallest
  // |--hide the clone
  // |--remove the clone

  var original = parent.closest( "div.modal" );
  var clone    = original.clone( true );

  clone
    .attr("id", newId + clone.attr( "id" ) )
    .find("*")
      .each( function( index, element ) {
        if ( element.id !== "" )
          element.id = newId + element.id;
      })
    .end()

    .after( original )
    .modal("show")
    .css({
      "visibility": "hidden",
    })
    .find( "#" + newId + pId ).find( "img" )
      .each( function() {
        largest = ( largest > $( this ).outerHeight() ) ? largest : $( this ).outerHeight();
       })
    .end()

    .modal("hide")
    .remove();

  // apply the style
  parent.css( "height", ( largest + 2 ) );

  ++cloneCounter;
}
```

Also the resize isn't working, but I'm not too worried about that at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was having a trouble with the original being removed is because I was using the wrong jQuery method. `.after` takes the content to be inserted inside the parenthesis. I should have been using `.insertAfter`.

[e.g.](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

`$(target).after(contentToBeInserted)`

`$(contentToBeInserted).insertAfter(target)`

Since I was calling the method on the clone I should have been using the second example.

Here is the fixed version of the function.

```
var cloneCounter = 0;

// Slow resize using jquery becuase
// the images are hidden.
function slowResize( parent, pId ) {
  // height of the largest image
  var largest = 0;

  var newId = "clone-" + cloneCounter + "-";

  // |find the modal that the parent is cloeset to
  // |-clone the modal
  // |--change the id of the clone
  // |--find all elements
  // |---change all the child ids
  // |--insert the clone into the dom
  // |--hide it from view, make dimensions available ( position: absolute, display: block )
  // |--find all the images related to the parent passed in
  // |---calculate which is the tallest
  // |--remove the clone

  var original = parent.closest( "div.modal" );
  var clone    = original.clone( true );

  clone
    .attr("id", newId + clone.attr( "id" ) )
    .find("*")
      .each( function( index, element ) {
        if ( element.id !== "" )
          element.id = newId + element.id;
      })
    .end()

    .insertAfter( original )
    .css({
      "display": "block",
      "left": "-9999px",
    })
    .find( "#" + newId + pId ).find( "img" )
      .each( function() {
        var c = this;

        if ( c.offsetParent !== null )
          largest = ( largest > c.height ) ? largest : c.height;
      })
    .end()

  clone.remove();

  // apply the style
  parent.css( "height", ( largest + 2 ) );

  ++cloneCounter;
}
```